# Jquery: how to sleep or delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want move up the object, delay 1000ms , then hide it,

i get the code:

```
$("#test").animate({"top":"-=80px"},1500)
      .animate({"top":"-=0px"},1000)
      .animate({"opacity":"0"},500);
```

i use ".animate({"top":"-=0px"},1000)" to implement delay, it's not good.

i want:

```
$("#test").animate({"top":"-=80px"},1500)
      .sleep(1000)
      .animate({"opacity":"0"},500);
```

any idea?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

How about `.delay()` ?

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

```
$("#test").animate({"top":"-=80px"},1500)
          .delay(1000)
          .animate({"opacity":"0"},500);
```

Comment: This works in this case but telling a thread to sleep and delaying an effect are two completely different things. jQuery even reminds of this in their documentation.

Answer (score 56):

If you can't use the `delay` method as Robert Harvey suggested, you can use `setTimeout`.

Eg.

```
setTimeout(function() {$("#test").animate({"top":"-=80px"})} , 1500); // delays 1.5 sec
setTimeout(function() {$("#test").animate({"opacity":"0"})} , 1500 + 1000); // delays 1 sec after the previous one
```