# jQuery sleep function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery: how to sleep or delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939980/jquery-how-to-sleep-or-delay)

```
var main = $('#main_content');
main.append("<img id=\"throbber\" src='/pre_config/css/images/throbber.gif' alt='Loading. Please wait.' />");
sleep(3000);
$("#main_content").load("/pre_config/function.php?type="+type+"piz&count=1", successCallback );
```

I want to sleep for 3 seconds here

```
sleep is not defined
[Break on this error] sleep(3000);
func2
```

Comment: Is [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939980/jquery-how-to-sleep-or-delay) what you're looking for?

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate, but the duplicate one won't help the OP. I think the OP is not aware that blocking methods in JavaScript won't work, and would be looking for an alternative paradigm.

Comment: Not really a duplicate.  The context and answer is different.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use a javascript `setTimeout()`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#main_content").load("/pre_config/function.php?type="+type+"piz&count=1", successCallback );
}, 3000);
```

---

**EDIT:**

To use `.delay()`, you would need to add the delayed code to an animation queue.

```
$("#main_content")
.delay(3000)
.queue(function( n ) {
    $(this).load("/pre_config/function.php?type="+type+"piz&count=1", successCallback )
           .dequeue();
});
```

Comment: +1... I cited your examples in my answer :) These should help the OP.

Answer (score 11):

Keep in mind that JavaScript is not only single threaded, but it shares the same thread with the page rendering. Therefore there are no in-built blocking functions in JavaScript, because that would make the page UI unresponsive.

You should consider using timers instead, using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout), [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval), or jQuery's [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/). Check out [@patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643562/what-is-sleep-in-jquery/3643569#3643569) for a couple of examples.