# Adding start delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 function moveto(coordinates) {
  step1 = coordinates[0];
  step2 = coordinates[1];
        var w = $(document).width();
        var h = $(document).height();

   $( "#full" )
   .animate({left: -(step1 * w)}, 2000 )
   .animate({top: -(step2 * h) }, 500 );
   } 
   var randomNum = randomNumbers();
   moveto(randomNum);
```

I need to add start delay of this function and to replay after a certain time

Comment: This question is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939980/jquery-how-to-sleep-or-delay
Basically use `delay()` (http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
var randomNum = randomNumbers();
moveto(randomNum);
```

To:

```
function doRandomMove(){
    var randomNum = randomNumbers();
    moveto(randomNum);
}
setTimeout(function(){
    doRandomMove()
    setInterval(doRandomMove, 10 * 1000);
}, 1000);
```

This will first call the change at 1 second, and keeps repeating after 10 seconds after first call.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `window.setTimeout("moveto(1,2)", 1000);`.

Your function will be called with a delay of 1000ms.

Comment: also use `setTimeout(moveto(randomNum), delay)` instead of `moveto(randomNum);` at the end of the function

Comment: Souldn't it be correctly `setTimeout("moveto(randomNum)", delay)` to avoid to call the function directly?

Comment: It should be `setTimeout(function(){ moveto(randomNum); }, delay)`. You are right, `moveto(randomNum)` would call the function immediately  but passing a string is bad practice. Pass an anonymous function instead.

Comment: Yes you are right. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout