# Jquery how to set interval

Tags: jquery, html

Im making slide show with jquery

How i can set interval between two function

for example:

```
$('#slide').css('background-image', 'url(1.jpg)');
//sleep 5000 ms
$('#slide').css('background-image', 'url(2.jpg)');
```

Comment: Have a look at this: [JQuery: how to sleep or delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939980/jquery-how-to-sleep-or-delay)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var counter= 0,
        imgs = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg'];

$('#slide').css('background-image', 'url('+ imgs[counter] +')');

setInterval(function(){
   counter++;
   if(counter > imgs.length-1) counter = 0;
   $('#slide').css('background-image', 'url('+ imgs[counter] +')');
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code is very unefficient. You get the #slide from the DOM and a line after you need to search again for the #slide element. It's faster to get the element and save it in a var ar something:

```
$('#slide').css('background-image', 'url(1.jpg)').css('background-image', 'url(2.jpg)');
```

And a pause can be done by the [`.delay( time )`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) method:

```
$('#slide').css('background-image', 'url(1.jpg)')
           .delay(1000)
           .css('background-image', 'url(2.jpg)'); // 1000 ms = 1 s
```

---

Thanks to Yoshi, `.delay` only works with `.animate`. So I tried it with `setTimeout`:

```
var foo = $('#foo')

foo.css('background', '#c33');

setTimeout( function() {
  foo.css('background', '#33c');
}, 2000); // 2000ms = 1s
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/fmzZ6/