# How to call function every 10 seconds?

Tags: angularjs

How to call function every 10 seconds? `$timeout` and `setTimeout` calling the function `dataTime` only one time, I would like repeating this constantly with no end.

```
 angular
.module('sfcLeftSiteBar')
.component('leftSiteBar', {
    templateUrl: '/Panel/LeftSiteBar/Templates/_leftSiteBar.html',


    controller: ['$http', '$window', '$state', '$scope', '$timeout', function ($http, $window, $state, $scope, $timeout) {

      function dataTime() {
            $http.post('/LeftSiteBar/TimeProvider').then(function (result) {

                console.log("czas" + JSON.stringify(result))
                $scope.datatime = result.data;
                console.log("czas2" + JSON.stringify($scope.datatime))
            })


        }



        // $timeout(dataTime, 10000);

      setTimeout(dataTime, 10000);


        }]
})
```

Comment: Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

Comment: Check this sample [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VIHU5jtuEadHa9aiNNyO) for $interval.

Comment: Thanks plunker but I have to take time from back-end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery how to set interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108923/jquery-how-to-set-interval)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`, like so:

`setInterval(dataTime, 10000);`

In order to be able to clear the interval at a later date, you need to assign a variable the return value of `setInterval` and then call `clearInterval` with your interval as parameter, like so:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(dataTime, 10000);
//clear interval at some point
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

But since you are using `AngularJS`, you might use the built-in interval method that takes care of any changes that might happen in the called function and automatically trigger a digest cycle.

`var angularInterval = $interval(dataTime, 10000);`

And cancel it like so:

`$interval.cancel(angularInterval);`

Comment: $interval is just a wrapper for window.setInternal but I still believe we should use it.

Comment: It is, but with the added functionality of being aware of any scope changes made by the interval function. Basically, `$interval` will trigger Angular's digest cycle, while `setInterval` won't.

Comment: you should add all that to your answer

Answer (score 7):

Angularjs has a built-in `$interval`, you should use it instead of regular `setInterval`:

```
controller: ['$interval', '$scope', function($interval, $scope) {
  function dataTime() {
    console.log('function works');
  }

  // start interval 
  var interval = $interval(dataTime, 10000);

  // call this method to stop interval
  $scope.stop = function() {
    $interval.cancel(interval);
  };
}
```

More info about [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

Comment: You need to cancel that interval eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Use angularjs `$interval` service to handle that. It is a angular service and comes with all you need in your application

```
      stop = $interval(function() {
        dataTime();
      }, 100);
```

You can also cancel the continous execution if you want.

```
      if (angular.isDefined(stop)) {
        $interval.cancel(stop);
        stop = undefined;
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>
<p>After clicking away the alert box, an new alert box will appear in 3 seconds. This goes on forever...</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

it will execute for every 20 secs

```html
setInterval(function(){
  $scope.callingFunction();// we can write any function
}, 20000)
```

Comment: This answer is not incorrect. It just need to clarify that in AngularJS shoule be used `$interval` instead of `setInterval` as explained in other answers

Comment: Please, read my comment again. I DID NOT SAY **not correct**. I SAID **not incorrect** (completely the opposite)