# Visually count up to number on page load

Tags: jquery, animation, timer

I have some numbered statistics on my page and I'd like to make them a little more visually appealing. I thought it might be cool to use jQuery to simulate counting up to that number.

So on page load, say the number is 32. The number would start at 0 and count up to 32, with some delay interval between each number.

[image]

How would I accomplish this? This is the code that I tried, but it's not working. It captures the number(s) on the page (there are 3 statRibbons), but it's not visually counting up where I can see each number 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. Ideally, it would count up each ribbon one at a time instead of at the same time, but if it requires bulky extra code, then that's okay. The .each should take care of this anyway, I would think.

```
$(function() {
  $(".statRibbon .bigStat span").each(function() {
      var tmp = this.innerHTML;
      var i = 0;
      while(i != tmp) {
          $(".statRibbon .bigStat span").innerHTML(i++);
          alert(i);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: It's not visually counting up to the number. I want to be able to see it rifle through the numbers, all the way up to 32. Right now it's just showing 32 immediately upon page load. http://jonathonmoore.com/mkt/

Comment: try this plugin ... http://cnanney.com/journal/code/apple-style-counter-revisited/

Comment: first it is html(value) not innerHTML(value) as it is a jQuery object and last you might need a TimeOut to display number little slower and more visible...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How does this work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/WpJxn/1/

Change the `50` at the end of the setTimeout function to change the speed it counts in miliseconds.

Comment: If the number is 0, it counts indefinitely instead of just staying at 0. How can this be prevented?

Comment: @PaulRuocco [try this](https://jsfiddle.net/WpJxn/698/) you can add an if statement before the increment and return if it should stay at 0.

Comment: In case you have large difference between the values like : 10, 78000, 1500 .. How would you make them in sync, like they would increment together, eather the large ones super quick and the smaller ones super slow?

Comment: @Hadh in that case we would just set a max exe time & then base the speed on the max number. http://jsfiddle.net/wkyup9Lf/

Comment: @AdamMerrifield And how would you do that?

Comment: @Hadh if you click the link in my last comment you will see a functioning example

Answer (score 4):

If someone wants to increase counter with certain increment then use,

// HTML

```
<span class="stat-count">10000</span>
```

// JS

```
$(function() {
    function count($this){
        var current = parseInt($this.html(), 10);
        current = current + 50; /* Where 50 is increment */

    $this.html(++current);
    if(current > $this.data('count')){
        $this.html($this.data('count'));
    } else {    
        setTimeout(function(){count($this)}, 5);
    }
}        

$(".stat-count").each(function() {
  $(this).data('count', parseInt($(this).html(), 10));
  $(this).html('0');
  count($(this));
 });

});
```

Jquery count numbers on page load with certain limit, counting time and counting increment.

Answer (score 3):

I'd replace the while with a setInteval

```
$(function() {
    $(".statRibbon .bigStat span").each(function() {
        var that = $(this),
            tmp = that.html(),
            i = 0,
            interval;

        that.html(0);
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            that.html(++i);
            if (i === +tmp) clearInterval(interval);
        }, 50);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you need some kind of sleep or delay in your loop before or after you alert the number. Try the `setTimeout` method.

You can find more information in this question here: [Jquery: how to sleep or delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939980/jquery-how-to-sleep-or-delay)