# Setting delay or timeout with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('.showmenu').bind("mouseenter", function (e) {
                $('ul.secondul').show();
});
$('.showmenu').bind("mouseleave", function (e) {
                $('ul.secondul').hide();
});
```

Is there a way to make the second function not fire right away, but after a 1 second delay? So when the user accidentally moves the mouse out of the dropdown menu tab, the tab would not close immediately and give the user a chance to move the mouse back on it.

Comment: Use hover: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939980/jquery-how-to-sleep-or-delay and SO MANY OTHERS.

Comment: @Colleen You are wrong. Delay() would not work in this case.

Comment: That was just one example of a duplicate, and furthermore, if you read the other answers in there, one of them explicitly mentions setTimeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('.showmenu')
.bind("mouseenter", function (e) {
    if($(this).data("timer"))
        clearTimeout($(this).data("timer"));
    $('ul.secondul').show();
})
.bind("mouseleave", function (e) {
    $(this).data("timer", setTimeout(function(){
        $('ul.secondul').hide();
    }, 1000));
});
```

Use `$(this).data` because it's a class and you can have more `.showmenu` items.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this -

```
vat timeout;
$('.showmenu').bind("mouseenter", function (e) {
                $('ul.secondul').show();
                clearTimeout(timeout);
});
$('.showmenu').bind("mouseleave", function (e) {
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
             $('ul.secondul').hide();
            },1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` (or other animations), you can chain it with `delay()` like so:

```
$('.showmenu').hover(

  function () {
    $('ul.secondul').stop(true,true).fadeIn(200);
  },

  function () {
    $('ul.secondul').stop(true, true).delay(1000).fadeOut(200);
  }

);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7VcwF/

Answer (score 0):

I believe jQuery hover is what you want to use:

```
$('.showmenu').hover(
    function() {
        $('ul.secondul').show();
    },
    function() {
        $('ul.secondul').hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: There doesn't need to be since it solves the stated problem: "So when the user accidentally moves the mouse out of the dropdown menu tab, the tab would not close immediately and give the user a chance to move the mouse back on it." Try it out.

Comment: I don't see how your code makes the tab "not close immediately" when the user "moves the mouse out". http://jsfiddle.net/7VcwF/1/ Since the OP didn't provide HTML, maybe I'm misunderstanding what is meant by "the dropdown menu tab".

Comment: I may have interpreted the question incorrectly, so I gave your answer a +1 after re-reading it and your answer. When using mouseenter and leave I have experienced similar unwanted behaviors and found using hover solved the problem.

Comment: Gotcha. I agree, `hover()` is nice and clean.